# How to Split the work of Spring Batch between several machines when the flow is reading from a single file?

Tags: spring-batch

My Flow is:

1. Read from a single file ( file size ~1TB )
2. Process each row
3. Write each row to 2 output files

How can i split the work between more than one machine in order to reduce the overall run-time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least three techniques for this use case:

- Physically partition the file using the [split](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_(Unix)) command (or equivalent) to create multiple partitions. Then use a partitioned step to process each partition.
- Logically partition the file (See `FlatFilePartitioner` in the attached sample in [BATCH-1613](https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-1613)) and use a partitioned step to process each partition
- Use a staging table to load the file in it, then use a partitioned step to process partitions on the table (for example IDs 1 -> 1000, 1001 -> 2000, etc)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud, these options sounds good and i will look more into it, however i was looking for a way to use the power of more than 1 machine and these suggestion refer to improving the performance on a single machine aren't they ?

Comment: A partitioned step can be executed locally (single JVM with multiple threads) or remotely (with multiple worker JVMs). You can find more details here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/spring-batch-integration.html#remote-partitioning and a sample here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-samples#remote-partitioning-sample.